# Accentuating Garlic flavour

Tags: garlic, flavor

I keep losing the flavour of garlic when I cook. For example, I chop up a lot of garlic and put it in a baked bean recipe or I make soup. I have been putting an enormous amount of garlic in these recipes and still can't taste it and I wonder if I'm preparing it incorrectly.
I just put on some chicken to go in a soup. Should I be chopping it up and putting it onto the chicken so that the chicken fat interacts with the garlic or wait to put the garlic into the broth?

In general, should garlic be prepared by having it interact with meat fats or should it be put on top at the end or boiled with other vegetables?
Is there a spice that will help make the garlic flavour more prominent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply put, the longer garlic cooks for, the weaker the flavour gets. If you want a super-garlicky hit, put it in at the last minute. Chopping it finer, or crushing it, also increases the flavour because more of the 'juice' is released.

Answer (score 0):

Agree - the lnoger it cooks the more subtle it becomes.  Also, some garlic has a more pronounced garlic flavor than others.

Comment: Might you know which garlic types have the most flavour... the uh... species or or whatever its called? :)

Comment: there are indeed two basic types: hard stem and soft stem garlic, with different properties...